# Find all the words in a unix file which begin with '#'

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Input file would look some thing like this :-

```
mary #had a little #lamb its #fleece #was white as snow
```

And the output should looklike

```
#had #lamb #fleece #was
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using `sed`**

```
sed -r 's/(^| )[^#][^ ]+//g'
```

**Test**

```
echo "mary #had a little #lamb its #fleece #was white as snow" | sed -r 's/(^| )[^#][^ ]+//g'
```

#had a #lamb #fleece #was

**Using `grep`**

```
grep -o "#[^ ]*"
```

**Test**

```
$ echo "mary #had a little #lamb its #fleece #was white as snow" | grep -o "#[^ ]*"
#had
#lamb
#fleece
#was
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be egrep or something to enable the regexp?

Comment: @DavidTriebe I dont think so. Works fine on `grep (GNU grep) 2.20
`

Comment: Huh, funny. "#[^ ]*" works but "#[^ ]+" doesn't without an -E, -P or so. Who would've thought?

Comment: Nice, the `grep` command is really smooth and short. Never used the `o` flag before.

Comment: Your `sed` command is producing the opposite of what the OP wanted though... otherwise, good idea.

Comment: @RyanJ Oops !!. Corrected. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind a leading space and don't want to match words that might contain a `#` in the middle such as `lit#tle`, you can also try this:

```
grep -o -P "(\s|^)#\w+"
```

Example:

```
echo "#mary #had a lit#tle #lamb its #fleece #was white as snow" | grep -o -P "(\s|^)#\w+"
#mary
 #had
 #lamb
 #fleece
 #was
```